# 'This' is undefined

Tags: vue.js, multi-select

I used Vue-Multiselect https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-getting-started to create a multi select input as follows

```
<multiselect v-on:select="myfilter()" v-model="cityF" 
:options="cities"  placeholder="City" label="name" track-by="name">

</multiselect>
```

But this is always undefined inside myfilter function. What is the problem? How can i solve it ?
Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: Please update the question explaining where `myfilter` defined and what makes you think that `this` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only guessing, but...

#### 1 You're using literally `This` instead of `this` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

This is easy to fix, just use 'this' instead of 'This'

#### 2 You likely have the function defined as

```js
methods:{
  myfilter: function() {
    console.log(this.whyNoWork);
  }
}
```

this will not use the correct scope, instead use

```js
methods:{
  myfilter: function() {
    console.log(this.isWorking);
  }.bind(this)
}
```

or **better yet**

```js
methods:{
  myfilter() {
    console.log(this.isWorking);
  }
}
```

#### 3 You should probably define the template as `myfilter` instead of `myfilter()`, unless you want to pass something to it

```
<multiselect v-on:select="myfilter" v-model="cityF" 
:options="cities"  placeholder="City" label="name" track-by="name">
</multiselect>
```

also more code usually means more help, otherwise we're just guessing.